# Caffeine modulating substances in coffee

Tags: psychopharmacology, drugs

From personal experimentation I know that caffeine affects me differently than coffee. Are there any known caffeine modulating substances found in coffee?

Comment: I can't help but notice that the question in the title is different from that in the body. Could you edit to make it clear. It may be wise to show  your prior research into the topic so as to avoid closure as lacking research. (The Wikipedia page on coffee is pretty good in this case).

Comment: From [Drink Golden Ratio](https://drinkgoldenratio.com/a/blog/why-does-coffee-make-you-poop): "Coffee contains thousands of compounds, but none have been definitively linked to the urge to defecate after drinking coffee. Although [some have suggested](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33383958/) molecules such as exorphins may be behind these effects, science hasn’t confirmed anything yet." It seems that what else is in coffee besides caffein that can affect us is an active field of research.

Comment: [Coffee appears to also stimulate release of the hormone gastrin](https://edition.cnn.com/2022/04/04/health/why-does-coffee-make-you-poop-wellness/index.html) this happens for decaf and regular. See also [It’s not clear why coffee can stimulate a bowel movement, but the speed of this effect suggests it’s mediated by the brain.](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/11/30/well/eat/why-does-coffee-make-you-poop.html)

Comment: I'm interested in caffeine modulating substances, thus I edited title and rejected your edit. Sorry for confusion...